# How do I create a ggplot in R from a non-linear model using the mgcv package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mgcv

I have a non-linear survival model which I have coded using the `mgcv` package. I can produce a regular plot, but I would like to be able to do code a `ggplot2` instead. How do I go about this?

Here is my code:

```
df <- structure(list(SurvYear =c(3L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 
8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 
7L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
9L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 
6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
9L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 
9L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 
9L, 5L, 4L), Gender = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L), Age = c(63L, 66L, 34L, 43L, 63L, 21L, 24L, 44L, 52L, 
59L, 27L, 32L, 30L, 20L, 56L, 55L, 35L, 26L, 53L, 43L, 39L, 19L, 
34L, 28L, 19L, 24L, 50L, 22L, 58L, 24L, 50L, 25L, 37L, 30L, 51L, 
69L, 23L, 49L, 22L, 46L, 58L, 31L, 23L, 53L, 59L, 25L, 38L, 44L, 
34L, 49L, 19L, 39L, 24L, 51L, 29L, 27L, 48L, 77L, 22L, 43L, 59L, 
49L, 60L, 51L, 49L, 47L, 50L, 44L, 41L, 44L, 50L, 42L, 46L, 54L, 
35L, 21L, 26L, 26L, 40L, 21L, 48L, 49L, 20L, 20L, 32L, 37L, 22L, 
36L, 46L, 28L, 39L, 35L, 51L, 39L, 49L, 57L, 46L, 18L, 52L, 47L, 
27L, 32L, 23L, 43L, 42L, 57L, 22L, 40L, 19L, 58L, 71L, 55L, 42L, 
20L, 51L, 21L, 20L, 61L, 36L, 54L, 19L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 34L, 22L, 
41L, 42L, 56L, 50L, 53L, 53L, 48L, 22L, 59L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 37L, 
68L, 24L, 26L, 61L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 50L, 62L, 61L, 29L, 18L, 40L, 
67L, 43L, 25L, 43L, 22L, 56L, 47L, 41L, 40L, 43L, 27L, 37L, 61L, 
35L, 23L, 54L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 45L, 49L, 63L, 49L, 44L, 44L, 23L, 
37L, 58L, 61L, 25L, 18L, 59L, 25L, 51L, 40L, 27L, 42L, 22L, 38L, 
22L, 45L, 33L, 32L, 36L, 53L, 52L, 19L, 45L, 53L, 27L, 65L, 25L, 
53L, 57L, 29L, 23L, 62L, 36L, 56L, 59L, 41L, 61L, 44L, 24L, 21L, 
38L, 29L, 55L, 33L, 18L, 21L, 19L, 65L, 24L, 59L, 34L, 25L, 45L, 
48L, 18L, 41L, 61L, 32L, 37L, 21L, 20L, 57L, 25L, 65L, 50L, 61L, 
32L, 27L, 19L, 50L, 63L, 19L, 45L, 20L, 36L, 20L, 19L, 53L, 39L, 
50L, 20L, 24L, 57L, 28L, 21L, 39L, 49L, 21L, 20L, 39L, 20L, 44L, 
19L, 39L, 53L, 29L, 60L, 43L, 21L, 23L, 30L, 42L, 42L, 51L, 35L, 
50L, 51L, 56L, 52L, 22L, 36L, 56L, 28L, 57L, 20L, 47L, 48L, 65L, 
71L, 21L, 70L, 23L, 63L), Highest_Educationmx = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
5L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L), Censor = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -300L))
```

Here is the script:

```
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)

#Run the model
Model1 <- gam(SurvYear~
                (Gender)+
                s(Age, k=50)+  
                s(Highest_Educationmx, k=7),
              weights=Censor, data=df, gamma=1.5, family=cox.ph())
summary(Model1)

#Build a perspective chart
vis.gam(Model1, view=c("Age","Highest_Educationmx"),
        plot.type="persp", color="gray", se=-1, theta=45, phi=25,
        xlab="Age", ylab= "Highest Education",
        ticktype="detailed", zlim=c(-5.00, 2.00))

#Plot individual predictors using plot command from mgcv
plot(Model1, all.terms=T, rug=T, residuals=F, se=T, shade=T, seWithMean=T) 

#Plot individual predictors using ggplot instead of plot command from mgcv
#UNSURE HOW DO TO THIS
```

Comment: technically, you're not plotting this model with `base`, but with  `mgcv::plot.gam`, a very long function (an S3 method, to be precise). In this function, you could try to identify which parts of the model object are used for plotting and then "translate" this into ggplot2. I admit I wonder if the more exploratory character of this visualisation justifies the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm biased (I wrote it) but you can use the [**gratia**](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/) package for this.

You can use the `draw()` function as a replacement for `plot.gam()`, and if you want total control, just use `evaluate_smooth()` to produce a tidy representation of the smooth which is then easily plotted using **ggplot2**.

Comment: Thank you very much. I took your suggestion and coded it up and it works perfectly. Full credit given to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script based on the suggestion from Gavin Simpson above:

```
library(gratia)

#Plot individual predictors using ggplot instead of the plot command from mgcv
sm <- gratia::evaluate_smooth(Model1, "Age") 
ggplot(sm, aes(x=Age, y=est)) + geom_line(size=1.0) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=est+se, ymin=est-se), alpha=0.20) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(20.00, 75.00), ylim=c(-2.00, 1.00)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(20.00, 75.00, 5.00)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-2.00, 1.00, 1.00)) +
  labs(title="Age") +
  xlab("Age") +
  ylab("Linear Risk Score") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=10)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", size=0.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=mean(df$Age), linetype="dashed", size=0.5)
```

Comment: That's great – I was away from my computer when I answered so it's good to have an example.